# how to fix proguard warning 'can't find referenced method' for existing methods 'clone' and 'finalize' of class java.lang.Object

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard, ical4j

I try to compress an android app that consumes `ical4j.jar`.

When i build the apk with proguard using `gradle proguardDebug` i get

- Warning: net.fortuna.ical4j.model.CalendarFactory: can't find referenced method 'void finalize()' in library class java.lang.Object

  - 6 additional similar warnings for `finalize()`
- Warning: net.fortuna.ical4j.model.CalendarFactory: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.Object clone()' in library class java.lang.Object

  - 6 additional similar warnings for `clone()`

I already verified that android-7 supports `finalize()` and `clone()`: "...\Android...\sdk\platforms\android-7\android.jar" has methods `finalize()` and `clone()` in class `java.lang.Object` .

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Note: this is not a duplicate of other 'proguard can't find referenced method' questions because in my specific case i think that the missing method should be there.

I am using

- proguard-4.11 with
- gradle-1.11

  - Groovy:       1.8.6
  - Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
  - Ivy:          2.2.0
  - JVM:          1.7.0_25 (Oracle Corporation 23.25-b01)
  - OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
- ical4j.jar 1.0.5

this is proguard config `proguard-rules.txt` that probably need some fix:

```
#  proguard-rules.txt
## ical4j also contains groovy code which is not used in android 
-dontwarn groovy.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.groovy.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Perf

-dontnote com.google.vending.**
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.**
```

This is my `build.gradle`

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
            classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:4.11'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'android'

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'commons-logging' // referenced in some portable lib. use androids internal instead
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 7
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }

            // used for testing. remove if it works as expected
            debug {
                runProguard true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.5'
        compile 'backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1'
        compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.8'
        compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    }
```

[Update 2014-12-20]

I have added my working configuration as answer below.

Note: with Current Android Studio 1.0 (android.buildToolsVersion >= '20') you must replace
**runProguard** with **minifyEnabled**

Example

```
    android {
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`net.fortuna.ical4j.model.CalendarFactory` extends `groovy.util.AbstractFactory` which extends `java.lang.Object`. However, the middle class is missing from your input (you're suppressing the corresponding warnings with -dontwarn). With part of the class hierarchy missing, ProGuard doesn't realize that CalendarFactory may access the protected methods `clone` and `finalize`, and it prints out these warnings.

Since your code probably doesn't use the class at all, you can suppress the warnings:

```
-dontwarn net.fortuna.ical4j.model.CalendarFactory
```

Or for covering all similar classes:

```
-dontwarn net.fortuna.ical4j.model.**
```

You shouldn't add any -keep options for this issue; the Android SDK already specifies the basic Android-related -keep options for you.

Comment: i removed as proposed `-keep class net.fortuna.ical4j.model.** { *; }` that further reduced apk by extra 60 kb. furtunately my android app doesnt use any of the groovy-dependant classes. I updated my own answer with the final solution

Answer (score 2):

This is my proguard config-file. Try copy-paste it

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose    

# standard, except v4.app.Fragment, its required when app uses Fragments

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
       public void *(android.view.View); 
}
```

Then add your code, as following:
When using

```
-dontwarn groovy.**
```

also add

```
-keep class groovy.** { *; }
```

Do it for all external libraries.

Comment: thanks for answer. i tried to add your config but the result was the same err. most android specific rules like `-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity` should come from `Android/.../tools/proguard/proguard-android(-optimize).txt`

Comment: did you tried to use -keep class ? I know that my file is using all of android specific rules. You may try turn of this system rules by removing ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt from project.properties file (that is when you use eclipse)

Comment: i did not use the keep for the groovy part because i donot want to keep the groovy part of the lib. However i am using the keep in my current workaround. I upvoted this answer from -1 to 0 because it helped me a lot although it was not the solution

Answer (score -1):

[update 2014-05-30 reformulated this text]

Thankyou to @EricLafortune answer that helped me to understand and solve the issue.

For others who want to compress android ical4j apps here is my working soluntion:

all classes with the `in library class java.lang.Object` - issue are from namespace

```
 net.fortuna.ical4j.model.**
```

so i added these lines to `proguard-rules.txt`

```
###################
# Get rid of #can't find referenced method in library class java.lang.Object# warnings for clone() and finalize()
# for details see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883028/how-to-fix-proguard-warning-cant-find-referenced-method-for-existing-methods
-dontwarn net.fortuna.ical4j.model.**

###############
# I use proguard only to remove unused stuff and to keep the app small.
# I donot want to obfuscate (rename packages, classes, methods, ...) since this is open source
-keepnames class ** { *; }
-keepnames interface ** { *; }
-keepnames enum ** { *; }
```

statistics:

- without obfuscation: 932 classes; apk 911kb.
- with obfuscation: 365 classes;apk 505kb

Comment: If you don't need/want to obfuscate, there is an option:  "-dontobfuscate" that you can use.